# div with dynamic min-height based on browser window height

Tags: viewport, css

I have three `div` elements: one as a header, one as a footer, and a center content `div`. 
 the `div` in the center needs to expand automatically with content, but I would like a `min-height` such that the bottom `div` always at least reaches the bottom of the window, but is not fixed there on longer pages.

For example:

```
<div id="a" style="height: 200px;">
  <p>This div should always remain at the top of the page content and should scroll with it.</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <p>This is the div in question. On longer pages, this div needs to behave normally (i.e. expand to fit the content and scroll with the entire page). On shorter pages, this div needs to expand beyond its content to a height such that div c will reach the bottom of the viewport, regardless of monitor resolution or window size.
</div>
<div id="c" style="height: 100px;">
  <p>This div needs to remain at the bottom of the page's content, and scroll with it on longer pages, but on shorter pages, needs to reach the bottom of the browser window, regardless of monitor resolution or window size.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just look for my [solution on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huston007/c4bauxny/2/), it is based on [csslayout](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%; /* needed for container min-height */
}
div#container {
  position: relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
  height: auto !important; /* real browsers */
  min-height: 100%; /* real browsers */
}
div#header {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #efe;
}
div#content {
  /* padding:1em 1em 5em; *//* bottom padding for footer */
}
div#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="header">header</div>

  <div id="content">
    content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You commented out the padding for the footer, I had to add that back in to accommodate for the footer area. I ended up using `padding-bottom: 50px` because my footer was 50px tall.

Comment: These two: `height: auto !important; /* real browsers */; min-height: 100%;` works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

I found this courtesy of [ryanfait.com](http://ryanfait.com). It's actually remarkably simple.

In order to float a footer to the bottom of the page when content is shorter than window-height, or at the bottom of the content when it is longer than window-height, utilize the following code:

Basic HTML structure:

```
<div id="content">
  Place your content here.
  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Place your footer information here.
</footer>
```

*Note: Nothing should be placed outside the '#content' and '#footer' divs unless it is absolutely positioned.*
 *Note: Nothing should be placed inside the '#push' div as it will be hidden.*

And the CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; /*min-height hack*/
  height: 100%;            /*min-height hack*/
  margin-bottom: -4em;     /*Negates #push on longer pages*/
}
#footer, #push {
  height: 4em;
}
```

To make headers or footers span the width of a page, you must absolutely position the header. 
*Note: If you add a page-width header, I found it necessary to add an extra wrapper div to #content. The outer div controls horizontal spacing while the inner div controls vertical spacing. I was required to do this because I found that 'min-height:' works only on the body of an element and adds padding to the height.*

*Edit: missing semicolon

Comment: Why not also include a demo-link and call it sticky-footer? http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: better use `min-height` instead of `height` for `html, body`, because otherwise it wouldn't stretch the background to site's full height, if the content would overflow over the window-size

Comment: This will show the footer even if the page content is longer than the screen.  Sometimes, this is not the wanted behavior.

Comment: **link is dead**, as the web designer who was own that blog, peace for his soul.

Answer (score 10):

If `#top` and `#bottom` have fixed heights, you can use:

```
#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
}
#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
#central {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bot: 100px;
}
```

---

### update

If you want `#central` to stretch down, you could:

- Fake it with a background on parent;
- Use CSS3's (not widely supported, most likely) `calc()`;
- Or maybe use javascript to dynamically add `min-height`.

With `calc()`:

```
#central {
    min-height: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

With jQuery it could be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var desiredHeight = $("body").height() - $("top").height() - $("bot").height();
  $("#central").css("min-height", desiredHeight );
});
```

Comment: but that won't stretch `#central` beyond its content...will it?

Comment: No. It does what you wanted, but it does not stretch the #central. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 9):

to get dynamic height based on browser window. Use **vh** instead of **%**

e.g: pass following **height: 100vh;** to the specific div

Comment: This is not right. Clearly, the op wants to size their content based on the window's height and certain other constraints.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere, the CSS function calc() can work nicely here.  It is now mostly supported.  You could use like:

```
.container
{
    min-height: 70%;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 300px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Comment: `calc` method is really usefull. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

No hack or js needed. Just apply the following rule to your root element:

```
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
```

It will automatically choose the bigger one from the two as its height, which means if the content is longer than the browser, it will be the height of the content, otherwise, the height of the browser. This is standard css.

Comment: Doesn't work here when its a div inside another div that has fixed height. That's because the 100% it's relative to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You propably have to write some JavaScript, because there is no way to estimate the height of all the users of the page.

Comment: javascript or jquery is fine. some of the pages just aren't that long, and maximized on my larger monitor, it would just look amazingly better if the footer actually footed the window in addition to the page (at least on smaller pages).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do this.

There is a `min-height:` css style, but it doesn't work in all browsers. You can use it, but the biggest problem is that you will need to set it to something like 90% or numbers like that (percents), but the top and bottom divs use fixed pixel sizes, and you won't be able to reconcile them.

```
 var minHeight = $(window).height() -
                 $('#a').outerHeight(true) -
                 $('#c').outerHeight(true));

if($('#b').height() < minHeight) $('#b').height(minHeight);
```

I know `a` and `c` have fixed heights, but I rather measure them in case they change later.

Also, I am measuring the height of `b` (I don't want to make is smaller after all), but if there is an image in there that did not load the height can change, so watch out for things like that.

It may be safer to do:

```
$('#b').prepend('<div style="float: left; width: 1px; height: ' + minHeight + 'px;">&nbsp;</div>');
```

Which simply adds an element into that div with the correct height - that effectively acts as min-height even for browsers that don't have it. (You may want to add the element into your markup, and then just control the height of it via javascript instead of also adding it that way, that way you can take it into account when designing the layout.)

Comment: i am familiar with css's `min-height:` property and how ie doesn't like to play nicely (that's why i use chrome), but i do know that you can use fixed lengths with `min-height:`.

Comment: You can use a fixed length, sure. But it won't scale dynamically to size of the screen.

Comment: OK, that all makes sense. Now please forgive me, I'm still in the process of learning to understand javascript, let alone write it...where would I put that script?

Comment: Oh boy. That's a bit much for me to answer in a comment. For one thing that uses the jQuery library, not just javascript. I think you should do some googling first. There are tons of tutorial sites for jQuery and javascript. (But, basically you want `<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">CODE GOES HERE</SCRIPT>` placed in the header section of the html. But you'll need a second script tag for the jQuery library before it will work.)

Comment: OK, thanks. Javascript and jQuery are next on my list of things to study...I guess this will just have to take a backseat for the time being.

Comment: SO I found [http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html](this) example of exactly what I want to do, with pure CSS. It's astoundingly simple...I don't know why I didn't see it. Now I just need to figure out how to modify it so that the header and footer span the full width of the page...

Comment: That's quite smart! It depends on min-height which doesn't work everywhere (but degrades very well when it doesn't work).

Comment: Yes, d*** IE and it's slower than death way of implementing new tech. Any suggestions on how to implement page wide header/footer? I have modified the code to make it work, but with my layout, the actual center div doesn't seem to expand...but the footer does what I want it to!

Comment: Try my method of adding a narrow transparent image of the proper height which forces the div to grow to at least that height. Give the image a css of `height: 100%;`.