# Let the bottom div fill the rest of the page

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure:
[image http://images.devs-on.net/Image/4eludampmz3Ylfm6-Bereich.png](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/4eludampmz3Ylfm6-Bereich.png)

I don't know the height of the head but I want the second container to fill the rest of the height.

I found some solutions when I would now the size of the head but I don't. I want that the upper container is fitting to its content while the second container is filling the rest of the window.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript/jQuery

```
var topDivHeight = $("#topdiv").height(),
totalHeight = $(document).height();
$('#bottomDiv').height(totalHeight  - topDivHeight );
```

Comment: I have problems with this when using it on the window resize event.
Then my document increases its height to the end :P

Comment: Yes I use your code and then my document is expanding to the bottom everytime I resize

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add # in $('#bottomDiv'). now it should solve your problem jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/546sP/2/.

Comment: No I think the mistake is to take the document height.. If I use the window height its working when resizing :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
position:absolute;
height:100% !important;
```

Comment: Not working if I append that to my bottom div. Then its not at full height

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a good, cross-browser way of doing this with pure CSS.  Your best bet is to use jQuery/javascript to adjust the height of your div to fill the screen.  Assuming your top div is 200px in height:

```
$("#bottom_div").css({
    minHeight: (($(window).height()) - 200) + 'px'
})
```

You will need to call this when your resize the screen, too.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from: [div with dynamic min-height based on browser window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527152/div-with-dynamic-min-height-based-on-browser-window-height) and does not depend on javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  Place your header information here.
</div>
<div id="content">
  Place your content here.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important /*min-height hack*/
  height: 100%;           /*min-height hack*/
  background-color: red;
}​
```

JSFiddle Test: http://jsfiddle.net/7SP9U/

Comment: Ah, but this extends the height of the container – whatever the height of previous elements is, that will be added as a scrollable difference at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use **display:table** property for this but it's work till IE8 & above. Write like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    display:table;
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
}
.container > div{
    display:table-row;
}
.header{background:red; height:10%;}

.content{background:blue}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Rvbk4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS-only solution that will only work in IE8, due to use of `display: table`.

The container must take full height, be absolutely positioned and take `display: table`. Its children will need `display: table-row` (if you want any decent styling below this level, you should really wrap the content in further wrappers with `display: table-cell` but I omitted this to make the example clear).

By default the rows will take up equal fraction heights of the parent, but you can make them shrink to fit their content by setting `height: 0` (or any other height).

Hope this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/barney/nXWbL/