# CSS: best way to have dynamic height header and content area to the bottom

Tags: css, layout

i'm having a `header#masthead` and a `section#main` underneath. The height of the header varies, however I want the `#main` area of the site to always fill the rest of the window to the bottom. I'd also like to specify a min-height for `#main` area.

Is that possible with pure css?

Or what's the best way of doing that?

Kind Regards,
sepp88

[image]

Comment: What happens if `#masthead` is bigger than the height of the screen?

Comment: that's whre the min-height of the #main section comes in. If e.g. #main is less than 800px high I want the site to have scrollbars.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579395/let-the-bottom-div-fill-the-rest-of-the-page I don't think it can be done without JS.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?  You put the Flexbox tag on it, but didn't bother to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a kind of [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) !

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KyP5/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="masthead">
    <p>dynamic height</p>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <p>reach the bottom</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* css reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#masthead {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* min-height hack */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -21em; /* size of main */
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

#main, .push {
    height: 21em; /* size of main */
}

/* such design */
#main {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

You can find more info about the `min-height` hack [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/).

Answer (score 0):

make sure body and html height are 100%.

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}

masthead {
    Width:100%;
    height:40px;
}

main {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```